# What is the syntax of CurrentDateTime in Microsoft Access 2007?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2007

I'm not good at english.So please abide.
i want to know what is the syntax of CurrentDateTime in Microsoft Access 2007.
i mean,In MSSQL Server 2008 , we can use GetDate() function.
but it can't use in Access.
i want to insert current datetime into access database.
So please answer me...
Thanks stackoverflow...

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
Now()
```

to give you the current date time or

```
Time()
Date()
```

For the respective portions.